# Creating a prefab on mouse drag in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse

When the user clicks and holds the mouse button (drags the mouse) I want to create a prefab using the mouse position - (similar to a brush drawing in paint - except change the brush mark with the prefab).

When the mouse is moved slowly this works fine. The problem I am having is if the user moves the mouse too fast the 'Update' function doesn't register all the mouse positions and each prefab is placed far from the previous prefab.

[image]

Initial Code:

```
public class Draw : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Brush;

    private bool _isDraging = false;
    private Vector3 _mousePos;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            _isDraging = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            _isDraging = false;
            return;
        }

        if (_isDraging)
        {
            _mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            _mousePos.z = 0;
            //I have added 'Physics.OverlapBox' so that the prefab doesn't overlap with the previous prefab
            var collide = Physics.OverlapBox(_mousePos, new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

            if (!collide.Any())
            {
                Debug.Log("Draw: " + _mousePos);
                Instantiate(Brush, _mousePos, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

```
void Update()
{
    //I use this to set the initial mouse position
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        _lastPlacedObjectLocation = _get2dMousePosition();
        //_isDraging is now removed
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        var currentMousePosition = _get2dMousePosition();
        var distanceTravelled = _lastPlacedObjectLocation - currentMousePosition;

        var stepDistance = distanceTravelled.magnitude;

        //I kept 1f - this is the distance between the prefabs - also my prefab size. Not sure if this is the best approach (the only way I could get it to work)
        for (float i = 0; i < stepDistance; i += 1f)
        {
            float progress = i / stepDistance;
            var placementPosition = Vector3.Lerp(_lastPlacedObjectLocation, currentMousePosition, progress);

            //Removed Physics.OverlapBox - in some places we want an overlap otherwise there is a gap between the prefabs
            Instantiate(Brush, placementPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        _lastPlacedObjectLocation = _get2dMousePosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just put the drag code in `Input.GetMouseButton` instead of using `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` and `Input.GetMouseButtonUp`.

Comment: @Programmer : It won't make the Update "faster"

Comment: This is a problem even photoshop and paint suffers from. If you want continuous pattern rather use a LineRenderer with repeating pattern. Or even a trail renderer.

Comment: @Hellium My comment has nothing to do with the `Update` function. The problem is not the `Update` function and the `Update` function is not slow. That comment will reduce OP's code into half of what it is now. It should be done with `Input.GetMouseButton` since OP wants click and hold effect.

Comment: @Programmer The problem he is suffering is most likely due to a large distance covered in a small amount of time. So it's like Hellium said - the update is too "slow" for the mouse movement. If you open up paint and use the  spray can you will see the exact same effect.

Comment: @Reasurria i'm pretty sure the spray can behaves like that by design, but i think that is indeed OP's problem. 
Op thinks to solve the problem by speeding up the rate at which `Update` is called (which is no cure-all and may be impossible).
Nothing comes without a price however, and the risk involved in my solution is slowing the update calls down a lot when there is a large distance to cover.

Comment: @Reasurria I don't know what's too hard to understand in my last comment. My comment is not an attempt to fix the problem. It shows the proper way to read from the mouse so that the `_isDraging` variable and those remaining logic code are not needed.  This is one of the places where `Input.GetMouseButton` should be used instead of `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` and `Input.GetMouseButtonUp`.

Comment: @TimothyGroote I agree it is like that by design. I also agree with your solution.

Comment: @Programmer Ok cool I appreciate the help you provided. I thought you were trying to answer the question with the comment.

Comment: @Programmer you are correct, that is indeed the cleaner way to do it, but you weren't very clear on what problem you were solving. (in fact, the problem you were solving wasn't mentioned)

Comment: @Reasurria No problem. Also `Update` function is **not** slow. The problem is `Input.mousePosition` and the way it is designed. It is made to be frame-rate dependent leading to problems like this. The proper way to get around this is to use C++ get real-time input from the mouse on all platforms or use the new un-released Unity Input System which does not depend on the frame-rate.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks man I didn't know that

Comment: @TimothyGroote I just noticed that. I tried to make it clear on my second comment with *"That comment will reduce OP's code into half of what it is now"* but that didn't work. Happy coding all!

Comment: @Antony Just out of curiosity - have you tried OnGUI() for mouse input?

Comment: @Reasurria I have not tried 'OnGUI()' for the mouse input. Thank you all for your input - I will post the updated version of the code shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since as you have noticed, your mouse speed is variable, and the update rate is not (it can be variable, or fixed. at any rate, it is not linked to the cursor's movement), that means your mouse cursor can move quite a distance between two update calls.

The simplest solution to the problem is to loop through the distance between the last known mouse location and the current one, and to fill in all the available space.

I haven't solved the problem completely for you ; there is room for improvement, and i can't really test this right now, but this should set you off in the right direction.

```
public class Draw : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Brush;

    private bool _isDraging = false;

    //we are going to keep track of the location where we last placed an object.
    private Vector3 _lastPlacedObjectLocation;

    private Vector3 _get2dMousePosition()
    {
         Vector3 newPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
         newPos.z = 0;
         return newPos;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            _isDraging = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            _isDraging = false;

            //keep 'old' mouse position up to date, so we do not draw in between dragging the mouse and releasing it. 
            _lastPlacedObjectLocation = _get2dMousePosition();
            return;
        }

        if (_isDraging)
        {
            Vector3 currentMousePosition = _get2dMousePosition();

            //now, we find how far the mouse has moved since the last step.
            Vector3 distanceTravelled = _lastPlacedObjectLocation - currentMousePosition;                

            //since we know the starting and ending point, all we have to do now is add the prefab instances, neatly spaced over the travelled distance.
           Vector3 stepDistance = distanceTravelled / spacing;

           //then, we interpolate between the start and end vector
           //you could make this a lot faster by determining how often your object fits in this space, but i'd like to leave you a little bit of a challenge, so i'm abusing the magnitude of the stepDistance ;)
           for(float i =0; i < stepDistance.magnitude; i+=0.1f)
           {
              float progress = i / stepDistance.magnitude;
              Vector3 placementPosition = Vector3.Lerp(_lastPlacedObjectLocation, currentMousePosition, progress);
              placePrefab(placementPosition);
           }



           //and then we update the last-placed-object location
           _lastPlacedObjectLocation = _get2dMousePosition();
        }
    }

    void placePrefab(Vector3 location)
    {
            //I have added 'Physics.OverlapBox' so that the prefab doesn't overlap with the previous prefab
            var collide = Physics.OverlapBox(location, new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

            if (!collide.Any())
            {
                Debug.Log("Draw: " + location);
                Instantiate(Brush, location, Quaternion.identity);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I will try the above and let you know

Comment: I just noticed there was an error in the examle, i wrote a `<` instead of a `/`. fixed that now, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Timothy has a good solution. I want to provide a completely different alternative.

Instead of instantiating prefabs like this you could use a LineRenderer and place the vertex positions where you are currently instantiating your prefabs.

On the material for the LineRenderer you can then adjust the x/y tiling to achieve a constant pattern repetition.

The drawbacks of this solution:

- Sharp corners will look hideous.
- Moving too slow will also cause visual artifacts.

Comment: you could solve the problems you outline by using a custom shader, but the complexity of that solution is far above the solution i suggested.
Since it *is* a viable solution, have an upvote.